# What sort of logical relationship exists in Kant's idealism?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, kant, philosophy-of-language, idealism

Space, time, and the categories are a priori intuitions/concepts of the mind. This entails the world we perceive is a world of mere appearance. Yet, I think I can also claim that the world being an appearance entails that space, time, etc. must be a priori.
In terms of logic, the relation, then, between the world as appearance and the a priori apparatus of the mind seems to be symmetrical.  The fact that space, time, etc. are merely in the mind entails the world is a mere appearance, and that the world is a mere appearance entails that space, time, etc. are merely in the mind.
In logic, does this relationship have a specific name?

Comment: [Reflexivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation)

Comment: [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence)? [Symmetric relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation)? Or are you asking specifically about equivalence between the world being an appearance and it being synthesized via forms of intuition and categories? By the way, appearances can, in principle, come about in ways different from Kant's combination of understanding and sensibility, so there is no such equivalence.

Comment: Your claim *the world being an appearance entails that space, time, etc. must be a priori* is simply logical tautology based upon Kant's metaphysics that time (space) and the categories are nothing but the purest perceptual intuitions and concepts of the mind's understanding and we cannot claim any sensible and intelligible judgement about the things-in-themselves supposed to exist objectively...